# How to convert EditField value to cell array?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I want to take a cell array from the user containing the number of zeros and poles of each transfer function in a system identification app that I am designing in MATLAB's app designer.

User enters something like this:

```
{[2,1], [1,0]; [1,0], [2,1]}
```

`EditField` or `TextArea` treats this input as a char array or string, But I want to re-convert it to a cell array of **numbers**, not **strings**. How is that possible?

Comment: One way is to send this to eval and get the cell array as output.

Comment: @Navan Good suggestion! Thank you. Post this as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate the string to get the resulting numbers. This works if it has numbers, variables and functions accessible from the workspace where you are running `eval`. See documentation for eval at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html. If there is a variable in the expression for example as, `{[2,1], [1,0]; [1,0], a}` with `a` defined in the base workspace then you need to use `evalin`. `evalin` lets you specify the workspace where the expression needs to be evaluated.

Finally if it is not a cell array and contains only an array of numbers then `str2num` also can do the job of converting the string to numbers.